# Trouble setting up Lua in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, lua

How can I include Lua in my project in Xcode?

I have installed Lua via the instructions on the website (curl, extract, make macosx install, etc).

I can reference lua

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

But when I go to use it, I get an error (even writing something as simple as the following)

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
lua_close(L);
```

It tells me :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. If you need further information, let me know and I can edit it in. Thanks!

EDIT: 
Added the -llua flag (SFML included the /usr/local/lib and include). Now getting "ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblua.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/liblua.a"

EDIT2:
I changed Base SDK to Latest OS X (OS X 10.9) and Build Active Architecture Only to "Yes" and now it will compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, select < ProjectName > with blue icon on top of the left pane (where all the sources are), then in main window select a target under Targets. In Build Settings tab, select All instead of Basic and set following parameters:

```
Other Linker Flags = -llua
Header Search Paths = /usr/local/include
Library Search Paths = /usr/local/lib
```

Assuming Lua headers were installed in /usr/local/include, and liblua.a in /usr/local/lib.

You may also use search field to find them.

Comment: I'm getting "ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblua.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/liblua.a"

Comment: Seems like Lua was built for i386 (because your project is definitely x86_64). Strange, because on my host vanilla Lua is 64-bit. Can you "find /usr/local/lib" in Terminal.app and post it here? What version of Lua is that?

Comment: Also output of "file /usr/local/lib/liblua.a" may help.

Comment: from the find, I have lua and lua/5.2, usr/local/lib/liblua.a: current ar archive random library.